# Asynchronous Acknowledgement - Spring Integration Application

Tags: asynchronous, spring-integration

Currently we have a Spring Integration application which accepts HL7 messages. The flow is as follows.

1. There is a message driven JMS inbound adapter which accepts the messages through ActiveMQ Queue.
2. Then the message goes through series of transformations and finally ended up in a service activator component to perform necessary business logic.

So far every thing looks good and recently the client requested that they want to have a acknowledgement for each message with the status. There can be two scenarios for a received message

1. Message executes successfully
2. Message fails with exception if the required criteria is not satisfied.

So we are thinking of implementing a acknowledgement mechanism which sends the acknowledgement back to the client through the above mentioned ActiveMQ queue or transmit via a tcp port.

Do we have any proven way/ patterns of doing these kind of acknowledgements? Is there any techniques which Spring Integration provides to achive this kind of scenario?

Appreciate your kind reply

Regards,
Keth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the inbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-inbound-gateway).

If the sender sets a replyTo header, the reply will be sent there; if not, you can configure a default replyTo destination.